# C# read bytes form serial port and parse from a queue

Tags: c#, parsing, serial-port, queue

I'm new to C# and I started to modify an existing application.
This application reads bytes from the serial port (115200 baud) and parses these bytes. The application reads byte after byte with a while statement:

```
public bool GetMessage(SerialPort sp, out ProtocolMsgT parsedMsg)
{
        try
        {
            if (sp.IsOpen)
            {
                while (sp.BytesToRead != 0)
                {
                   // Parsing
                }
             }
         }
}
```

The bytes are sent from an embedded system and the bytes represent log message with length up to 128 byte. In particular the log messages are printed into a multiline textbox.

Actually the application shows only the last received log. I think that is due to the read and parsing procedure.

Which is the best way to parse messages at high baud rate?

I think to use a task that read continuously from the serial an stores the byte into a queue. An use another task to parse the bytes an manage the GUI.

Should this works?

Thanks!

Comment: _"**I think** that is due to the read and parsing procedure."_ That's a bad starting point. If you want to change the code, you should **know** this is the problem. Which I doubt by the way.

Comment: I'm not the application builder, so I don't know exactly which could be the problem. And second I'm really new to C#.

Comment: 2/2 : I suspect it is more because each parsed ProtocolMsgT will clear the textbox of the previous message. So, if you want the previous ones, don't clear them.

Comment: @Fildor: I don't think so, because if I send a message every 500 ms all messages are show,

Comment: _"I'm really new to C#"_ - Your problem would be the same in any language. If you don't know what the problem is, how can you come up with a solution? Do more research, first. If you continue to follow your "plan" you are likely to break the code big time.

Comment: _"if I send a message every 500 ms all messages are show"_ this could be related to this line: `while (sp.BytesToRead != 0)` ... but also on how the parsing works. But you should really dig deeper into this part before doing anything.

Comment: Also, the way `GetMessage` is called may play a role. You might want to first try and only make it consume one complete message (instead of the complete stream) and return. Then have the caller call the method again for the next complete message and so on.